# Blazor Text Editor not able to bind value on form (create/edit)

Tags: data-annotations, blazor, rich-text-editor, blazored

I am using Blazor Text Editor from source below.

Source - https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor

I successfully integrated it with my create and edit form, however not able to bind-Value to it. Because of this my Data Annotation Validation is failing.

Internally blazor is using Quill Editor, I am not looking for javascript option.

Sample Code of editor

```
<BlazoredTextEditor  @ref="@QuillNative" Placeholder="Enter non HTML format like centering...">
      <ToolbarContent>Some editor stuff here</ToolbarContent>
<BlazoredTextEditor
```

Could anyone please help me. How to bind-Value or correct approach without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Vencovsky - thanks of you prompt response, I was already aware of these methods however was curious to know if anybody had tried different option.

Below is what I did..

FORM -- This is common form for create & edit. OnValidSubmit will call respective Create/Edit method.

```
<EditForm Model="Entity" class="contact-form" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
//My form fields here
//Commented the validation from that particular field
@*<ValidationMessage For="@(() =>Entity.field)" />*@

<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="submit" @onclick="***getEditorData***" class="btn" 
    style="border:2px solid #555555;"><span>Save</span></button>
 </div>
</EditForm>
```

METHOD -- getEditorData() gets fired before OnValidSubmit()

```
public async void getEditorData()
{
  Enity.field = await this.QuillNative.GetHTML();
}
```

So in my final Entity on OnValidSubmit() I receive all fields along with editor data..

Hope this help if anyone is trying to do so..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't bind a value to it, but you should use the provided methods

Methods

- **GetText** - Gets the content of the editor as Text.
- **GetHTML** - Gets the content of the editor as HTML.
- **GetContent** - Gets the content of the editor in the native Quill JSON Delta format.
- **LoadContent** (json) - Allows the content of the editor to be programmatically set.
- **LoadHTMLContent** (string) - Allows the content of the editor to be programmatically set.
- **InsertImage** (string) - Inserts an image at the current point in the editor.

To use these methods you need a reference of it

```
@* Getting the BlazoredTextEditor reference*@
<BlazoredTextEditor @ref="@BlazoredTextEditorRef">
    @* rest of the code*@
</BlazoredTextEditor>
```

And in some code in your class you can do

```
void LoadData(){
    //var html = BlazoredTextEditor.LoadHTML(SomeDataToLoad)
    BlazoredTextEditor.LoadText(SomeDataToLoad)
}

void ValidateData(){
    //var html = BlazoredTextEditor.GetHTML()
    var text = BlazoredTextEditor.GetText()
    // do something to validate text
}
```

You can call these methods and use the referece in other methods, this is just an example on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did this:
1- to bind the value on load:

```
 <BlazoredTextEditor @ref="@QuillHtml">
        <EditorContent>
            @((MarkupString)infoBlock.Description)
        </EditorContent>
    </BlazoredTextEditor>
```

2. to get value on submit

   ```
    <EditForm Model="infoBlock" OnValidSubmit="LocalOnValidSubmit">
   ```

   ...

   ```
     @code {
    ....       
            [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
            BlazoredTextEditor QuillHtml = new BlazoredTextEditor();

            private async Task LocalOnValidSubmit()
            {
                      infoBlock.Description = await this.QuillHtml.GetHTML();
                      await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(this);//to call event handler passed by parent after the HTML prepared for main bound class
            }
        }
   ```